# How to update data store field in Svelte

Tags: svelte

I have a data store and I update the value when a button is pressed. The value on the page ( labelled 'data_sto') does not get updated. What do I need to do?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/f7e8d8e17f864790aa77770e92b0a39f?version=3.52.0)

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
  import Child, { update_sum } from './Child.svelte';
  import { board } from './data_store';
    
    let my_sum = 0
    
    function refresh() {
        my_sum = update_sum();
        console.log('after update', $board);
    }
</script>

<h1>Test imports</h1>
<button on:click={refresh}>Click</button>
<div>
    data_sto {$board.sum}
</div>
<div>
    my_sum {my_sum}
</div>
<Child />
```

**Child.svelte**

```
Child text

<script context="module">
    import { get } from 'svelte/store';
  import { board } from './data_store';
    
    export function update_sum() {
        let board_data = get(board);
        board_data.sum = 12;
        return board_data.sum;
}
</script>
```

**data_store.js**

```
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';

let board_store = {
    sum: 1,
};
export let board = writable(board_store);
```

(This functionality is represents the  essential elements extracted from a larger Svelte project)

Comment: You need to call `.set` in your `Child.svelte`. Since you're using `get` on the store, any assignments to that internal data won't be reactive. Try adding `board.set(board_data)` and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.set` on your `board` store to update the store. The reason why your current code doesn't work is that it's retrieving the data with `get`, `board_data` no longer becomes reactive and rather it is just a regular JSON object

```html
Child text

<script context="module">
    import { get } from 'svelte/store';
    import { board } from './data_store';
    
    export function update_sum() {
        let board_data = get(board);
        board_data.sum = 12;
        board.set(board_data) // to update the store
        return board_data.sum;
    }
</script>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4c94db71273d4d34a2816e7519552652?version=3.52.0)